# Video Processor MFT causes error 'The request is invalid in the current state'

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I am using Media Foundation to create a webcam viewer.
Critical to this application is that the webcam stream is horizontally mirrored.
I am using [the Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft)
to achieve this.
Here's the relevant code to add the MFT:

```
void tryMirror(IMFPMediaPlayer* pPlayer) {
    IMFTransform* pMFT = NULL;
    IMFVideoProcessorControl* pVPC = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMFT));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, ...) failed", hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pMFT->QueryInterface(&pVPC);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"pMFT->QueryInterface(&pVPC) failed", hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pVPC->SetMirror(MIRROR_HORIZONTAL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"pVPC->SetMirror(MIRROR_HORIZONTAL) failed", hr);
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pPlayer->InsertEffect(pMFT, FALSE);  // Not optional - critical functionality
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"m_pPlayer->InsertEffect(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT) failed", hr);
        goto done;
    }

    done:
    SafeRelease(&pMFT);
    SafeRelease(&pVPC);
}

// class CPreview implements IMFPMediaPlayerCallback as follows

void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CPreview::OnMediaPlayerEvent(MFP_EVENT_HEADER* pEventHeader) {
    switch (pEventHeader->eEventType)
    {
        //...
        case MFP_EVENT_TYPE_MEDIAITEM_SET:
            OnMediaItemSet(MFP_GET_MEDIAITEM_SET_EVENT(pEventHeader));
            break;

        case MFP_EVENT_TYPE_PLAY:
            OnMfpPlay(MFP_GET_PLAY_EVENT(pEventHeader));
            break;
    }
}

// Called after I set the webcam media source
void CPreview::OnMediaItemSet(MFP_MEDIAITEM_SET_EVENT* /*pEvent*/)
{
    HRESULT hr = m_pPlayer->Play();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"m_pPlayer->Play() failed", hr);
    }
}

void CPreview::OnMfpPlay(MFP_PLAY_EVENT* pEvent) {
    if (FAILED(pEvent->header.hrEvent)) {
        ShowHResultErrorMessage(L"OnMfpPlay failed", pEvent->header.hrEvent);
        WCHAR msg[1000];
        HRESULT hr = StringCbPrintf(msg, sizeof(msg), L"Event type: 0x%X", pEvent->header.eEventType);
        ShowErrorMessage(msg);
        return;
    }
}

void ShowHResultErrorMessage(PCWSTR errContext, HRESULT hrErr) {
    _com_error err(hrErr);
    LPCTSTR hrErrMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    WCHAR msg[1000];
    HRESULT hr = StringCbPrintf(msg, sizeof(msg), L"%s (HRESULT=0x%X, %s)", errContext, hrErr, hrErrMsg);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

On my development machine, this program runs without error, exactly as desired.
However, on a different user machine,
it fails with this error:

```
OnMfpPlay failed (HRESULT=0xC00D36B2, The request is invalid in the current state.)
```

That is,
this error comes through on the `OnMediaPlayerEvent` callback
of the `IMFPMediaPlayerCallback` object.

I do know a few things about the machine that this fails on:

- The user has also run a modified version,
  with the MFT set to optional, like so:
  `pPlayer->InsertEffect(pMFT, TRUE)`.
  In this case, the program runs,
  but the mirroring MFT has no effect.
  The error is definitely caused by this MFT.
- This user is running Windows 10, version 1909.
  The Video Processor MFT is clearly *available*.
  Its API claims to work - all `HRESULT`s are successful.

**This error, "The request is invalid in the current state", could mean anything, and
I can't find any way to get more observability.
What does 'The request is invalid in the current state' mean?
Why is it generated by adding a Video Processor MFT, only on some machines?
How can I debug this with a more specific error?**

Comment: Incompatible media type? Capture in NV12.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChourdakis. Do you mean you think the error is that the webcam device is providing frames in a format that's not in [the list of supported inputs for the Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft#input-formats)?

Comment: Possibly. I have messed a lot with MF in my sequencer and I have seen MFTs to fail on media types, mostly. Try to instantiate the color conversion DMO and convert to NV12 the sample you get from the camera before passing it to the transform.

Comment: Use MFTrace to get a trace to get some more hints about what might be happening.

Also, get a DXDiag from the machine with the problem.  There could be hints in the DXDiag,  are there other video processor than the "Microsoft Video Processor MFT"?  are the video drivers up to date on that machine?

Comment: Thanks @AdamMarks - I haven't tried those! I'll give it a go!